# How to change Magento website to mobile compatible

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2. I want to keep my website Mobile Compatible also (like responsive) by which user can easily access the website through their mobile. Please advice me how can I do it.

Here is the link of my website: http://baku.com.au/

Answer (score 0):

Below are the links ,please check.
Hope they are helpful for you.

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/how-to-mobilize-your-magento-site-for-iphone-android-mobile-commerce/

http://www.redlightblinking.com/blog/setup-your-magento-mobile-theme-using-multiple-websites

Its a easy functionality provides by magento

Comment: it is not compulsory to always vote up your answer . if your answer helpful to other then user can voteup your answer or accept your answer

Comment: Yes i know very well , i am not forcing anyone , its just a reminder if my answer is helpful then vote up,so that in future if anyone have the same question can refer my answer. Go On...